# Convert or cast varchar MM/DD/YYYY data into datetime MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

I'm trying to convert/cast varchar mm/dd/yyyy data into datetime mm/dd/yyyy format so that I can query a range using a between clause.

I've seen a similar question asked previously, but without the slashes in the date and I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: A `datetime` doesn't have a format. At least not in the way you're thinking.

Comment: Once you converted your `VARCHAR` on a given format to `DATETIME`, there is no longer a `MM/DD/YYY` format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do a proper range query, you can convert from your bad regional formats in a predictable way, and then use an open-ended range. Now this doesn't protect you from someone entering `06/08/2013` and meaning August 6th instead of June 8th, but if you support free text entry, that's a risk you'll have to take.

```
DECLARE @s DATETIME, @e DATETIME;

SELECT @s = CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/13/2013', 101),
       @e = CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/26/2013', 101);

SELECT <cols>
FROM dbo.table_name
  WHERE datetime_column >= @s
  AND datetime_column < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @e);
```

Ideally, you wouldn't allow users to type in regional nonsense like `m/d/y`. If you control the input format to the stored procedure, you can send an unambiguous date literal like `YYYYMMDD`. Or better yet, use a strongly typed parameter. The more you can take away from users entering ad hoc nonsense the less headache you'll have. Please read these articles:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I think you meant SET @s =

Comment: @kevro no, I didn't. `SET` only allows you to assign one variable at a time. I'm assigning more than one.

Comment: It worked like a champ. Thanks for the quick response and the follow-on articles.